# jQuery trouble finding / setting objects in multi dimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I am trying to use jquery to loop through a selection and create a 2d array from the values:

with the code below my desired output would look like this:

`object {Monday => hours[0] = '1a-2a',hours[1] = '2a-3a', Tuesday => hours[0] = '4p-5p', hours[1] = '5p-6p'}`

Assuming my `.each` selector looks something like this:

```
<ol id='selectable'>
   <li data-day='Monday' data-time='1a-2a' class='ui-selected'></li>
   <li data-day='Monday' data-time='2a-3a' class='ui-selected'></li>
   <li data-day='Tuesday' data-time='4p-5p' class='ui-selected'></li>
   <li data-day='Tuesday' data-time='5p-6p' class='ui-selected'></li>
</ol>
```

Im trying to use the code below to get my desired output put I keep receiving the error message:

"TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'hours' in undefined(…)"

```
var days = new Array('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday');
var selection = [];
var i;
    for (i = 0; i < days.length; ++i) {
        $( ".ui-selected", "#selectable" ).each(function() {
            if($(this).attr( 'data-day' ) == days[i]){
                if(!(days[i] in selection)){
                    selection.push(days[i]);
                    if(!("hours" in selection[days[i]])){
                        selection[days[i]] = {hours:[]};
                    }
                }
                selection[days[i]]['hours'].push($(this).attr( 'data-time' ));
            }
        });
        console.log(selection);
    }
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `selection` to be an object, not an array, like so:

```
var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
var selection = {};
var i;
for (i = 0; i < days.length; ++i) {
    $( ".ui-selected", "#selectable" ).each(function() {
        if($(this).data( 'day' ) == days[i]){
            if(!(days[i] in selection)){
                selection[days[i]] = {};
                if(!("hours" in selection[days[i]])){
                    selection[days[i]] = {hours:[]};
                }
            }
            selection[days[i]]['hours'].push($(this).data( 'time' ));
        }
    });
    console.log(selection);
}
```

Working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/wehdnm20/1/

Comment: You bet. Glad I could help :)